# Bypass disabled autorun for USB devices on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, autorun, autoplay

The following was mentioned in a post regarding autorunning from a flash drive:

> "To get autorun working under Windows 7 requires special firmware on the drive and/or some specialty software preinstalled on the machine."

Could this be elaborated on?

Is there anything at all that I could do, or a program I could write, to bypass the Windows 7 AutoPlay disable?

Answer (score 4):

I think we may need some clarification on Autoplay Vs. Autorun.

> **AutoPlay**
>
> AutoPlay is a Windows feature that lets you choose which program to
>   use to start different kinds of media, such as music CDs, or CDs or
>   DVDs containing photos. For example, the first time you try to play a
>   music CD, AutoPlay asks which media player you want to use, if you
>   have more than one installed on your computer. You can change AutoPlay
>   settings for each media type.
>
> **Autorun**
>
> Autorun is a technology used to start some programs or enhanced
>   content (such as video content on a music CD) automatically when you
>   insert a CD or another media type into your computer. This is
>   different from AutoPlay, but the result is often the same: when
>   inserted, the CD starts automatically, using a particular program.
>   Autorun is incorporated into the media types that use it, and you
>   can't modify it.
>
> When you try to play a CD or another media type that uses autorun,
>   AutoPlay asks you to choose an action to perform (for example, to play
>   the autorun content or to skip it).
>
> [Source:](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-vista/Whats-the-difference-between-AutoPlay-and-autorun)

**Autorun on USB/Removable devices has been turned off in Windows since April 2009.**

To enable Autorun you will have to change some settings on your computer.

1. Click Start, type `gpedit.msc` in the Start Search box, and then press
   <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
2. If you are prompted for an administrator password or for
   confirmation, type the password, or click Allow.
3. Under `Computer Configuration`, expand `Administrative Templates`, then expand `Windows
   Components`, and then click `Autoplay Policies`.
4. In the Details pane, double click on *Turn off Autoplay* ,and make sure that it is set to `disabled`
5. In the Details pane, double click on *Default behavior for Autorun*, set it to `Enabled` and then select `Automatically execute the autorun commands`
6. Restart your computer.
   [image][image]

Note that you will not be able to bypass the Autorun policy, it will only work on the intended media types such as CD's DVD's and Video Games.

Comment: Thank you very much. If one of the flash drive partitions emulated a CD drive, would I be able to autorun content then?

Comment: Yes, and you'll need a [U3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U3) Drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can't bypass the OS' control of AutoPlay - if it's your own computer you can configure as per [@Petr Abulin's answer](https://superuser.com/a/538165/32245). If you're looking to distribute flash drives to others you can configure the `autorun.inf` on the drive to enable AutoPlay, for users who haven't disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Control Panel -> Hardware -> AutoPlay`, and configure autorun the way you want.

Comment: This doesn't answer @Scott's question regarding bypassing AutoPlay being disabled. This is how to disable AutoPlay.

Comment: Oh, seems like I misunderstood @Scott question. I guess this is similir to breaching core security features of an OS, since it's intended so it's behavior could be changed only by computer admin, and not some malware.

Comment: Agreed, as per my answer. I think he may be looking for info on how to configure it generally so your answer may still be useful to him.

Comment: I am looking in fact to do it in a way that any computer I plug it into autoruns specific content. What if I make a partition that emulates a CD drive? Could I put the autorun content on there, hide the content and make that partition unformattable (or at least hidden?)

Comment: "Any computer" presents a bit of an issue. Windows/Mac/Linux/Unix? Thin clients, laptops, servers, netbooks, desktops? You could setup the AutoPlay equivalent for whatever you're targeting, but you can't stop the user from disabling AutoPlay.