# Logger that saves usb drive changelogs?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

So I want to create a script that logs every change to every file on my USB thumb drive ON MY COMPUTER, so I can trace which file got added/removed from the last check so I can back up my files somewhere else.

Due to my unfamiliarity with the Windows commands, I don't know how to do this; may anyone please help me?

Comment: A) what have you tried so far? B) is this script supposed to be able to track situations where the USB drive is stuck into a different computer, or does it only have to work on a single computer? Please use the EDIT button to add this and any other relevant information to the question itself.

Comment: @music2myear I've added that I need this to work on any computer. As I mentioned, I'm not familiar with the Windows scripts so I really didn't manage to do anything other than creating the autorun file on my USB drive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bypass disabled autorun for USB devices on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/538153/bypass-disabled-autorun-for-usb-devices-on-windows-7)